# How can I have an abstract and introduction on the same page of a Latex document?

Tags: latex, abstract

I need to change the layout of my document to send my paper to a conference. My abstract is currenly on a separate page. The introduction should be straight after the abstract, not on the separate pages.

> How can I have an abstract and an introduction on the same page?

Comment: didn't I see the same (or similar) question just a couple minutes ago?

Comment: Same OP, same document (I guess), different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conference should provide with at least information on how to format your paper, and often they have LaTeX styles ready, for instance [at IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/web/publications/authors/index.html), or [at ACM](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) (btw, the IEEEtran class is bundled in TeXlive).

They are pretty standard customizations of the basic article class from LaTeX and actually I never saw one format the abstract on a separate page.

Comment: I have to use the ACM-style, and I am using TeXlive.

Answer (score 2):

This is a function of the document class, so it really depends.

Some [info on the behavior of the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`,...) (PDF)](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf),

Good general advice: consider using the [memoir class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/), which is vastly configurable. All the answers are in [the docs (PDF)](http://www.ctan.org/get/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

Comment: Your "the docs" link requires a login, when you click on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `notitlepage` option, i.e.:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Your conference is probably long due but maybe someone else can use this.)

You can put this before your abstract:

```
\def\abstract{
   \vfil
\begin{center}%
{\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}}%
\end{center}
\quotation
}

\def\endabstract{\par
\endquotation
}
```

This way you can customize your abstract like you want it, without having it on a separate page.